# Show and hide an image within a td in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

Im trying to load an image if a user has a status of 'admin' but having trouble as I am new to using Rails.

Here is what i have come to:

```
%td= recruiter.admin? ? image_path('admin.png') : ''
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Any error?

Comment: Laurence- please describe a bit more about your issue. Can you tell us what's happening or what's not happening? What do you expect? Any of those would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

To show image you should use image_tag, not image_path. image_tag will generate IMG html tag, while image_path gives you an assets path. Read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: I meant to type image_tag, sorry. The problem was actually due to the code above requiring braces rather than brackets.